# How can I pass a string from an onclick event to another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, encapsulation

I am new to encapsulation.  I would like to pass a string from the OnClick event of one of my buttons to a private method in another class.  When I try to set the string from inside the method now it says that variable isn't recognized How can I safely pass it in?

My OnClick Event:

```
public partial class ClassOne
  protected void lnkbtnKeySearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           string myNewString = "Change the value of the string";
      }
```

Class I want to pass it into:

```
public partial class ClassTwo
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData();
        }
    }
    private void LoadData()
    {
        {
            string filterText = myNewString;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you need to make the method (or *a* method) public/internal and call it by passing the string as a parameter

Comment: @musefan Are you saying I just make lnkbtnKeySearch_Click public? Can you show me an example using the code provided?

Comment: please post the code where you instantiate `ClassTwo` and where you want to call `LoadData`

Comment: No. I am suggest you make: `public void LoadData(string aString){ }` I think you need to read some basic C# tutorials. Especially in relation to "scope"

Comment: Why not store this value in session object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to hold the value of the string inside a session variable:

```
protected void lnkbtnKeySearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Session["myNewString"] = "Change the value of the string";
}

private void LoadData()
{
     string filterText = Session["myNewString"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This solved my issue.  I removed the extra semicolon after the .ToString method.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to make MyNewString static.

```
public partial class ClassOne
{
  public static string MyNewString{set;get;} 
  protected void lnkbtnKeySearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       MyNewString= "Change the value of the string";
  }
}
```

Then

```
    public partial class ClassTwo
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData();
        }
    }
    private void LoadData()
    {
        {
            string filterText = ClassOne.MyNewString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I won't choose to hold a string in a static variable, because all the clients of the application will share the same content of the string.

Comment: I agree with you but if he do not use standard things I thought he do not want use them so I suggested this way. And I mentioned that it is one of the possible ways. Session[""] is possible way but we should know that it clears its state after some time.